# pygtk: What class should my custom widgets inherit from?

Tags: python, inheritance, gtk, pygtk

When making a custom widget in pygtk, what class should it inherit from? I want to be able to put the widget inside other widgets, but I don't want other people to put stuff in mine. Usually I make my widgets inherit from `gtk.HBox` or `gtk.VBox`, and that works fine, but it is possible then for someone to do a `pack_start()` on my widget and cause strange things to happen. I'd inherit from `gtk.Widget` but then how do I add things to it? I'd inherit from `gtk.Container` or `gtk.Bin` but the docs say they are abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom widget contains other (probably standard) widgets, you could simply raise an exception in the overridden `pack_` methods. That way, nobody can put stuff in it (easily). Inside your class, you then have to use `super(...).pack_xxx` instead of `self.pack_xxx`.

But it's probably better to derive from `gtk.Container`. Then you'll have to implement its abstract methods like `do_add(self, widget)`.

In case you only draw custom content (no children), there's no need to derive from a container widget. See the [tutorial on pygtk.org](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/writing-a-custom-widget-using-pygtk/writing-a-custom-widget-using-pygtk.htm).